# Gitversion not working on teamcity - FAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-fake

I am trying to use below code to get the git version no , on my local machine it is working fine , but on teamcity it is giving an error .

here is the code :

```
open GitVersionHelper  
// version
let version = GitVersion id
printfn "##teamcity[buildNumber '%s']" version.FullSemVer

let major = version.Major.ToString()
let minor = version.Minor.ToString()
let patch = version.Patch.ToString()
```

and when I see my build log on teamcity , it shows :

```
System.Exception: GitVersion.exe failed with exit code 1
Fake.GitVersionHelper.GitVersion@62.Invoke(String message)
Fake.GitVersionHelper.GitVersion(FSharpFunc`2 setParams)
```

is this related to the missing libraries or what ?

Comment: Have you configured TeamCity to use agent checkout per [the docs](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/teamcity/)? By default the agent won't have the `.git` folder, so GitVersion won't have anything to calculate the version from.

Comment: yes , but once I commit this folder , then do I have to  update this folder manually when version changes . Is there any way where this manual work can be reduced .

Comment: I don't follow. What manual work? You can't commit the `.git` folder, it's part of how git works. You need to change the TeamCity config to use agent checkout so the agent checks the branch out from git (thus including the `.git` folder) rather than the server running the checkout and passing the files across.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , I just tried what you suggested , but still  not able to find out .git folder while building .